# GRUB bootloader won't install when installing Linux Mint on Surface Book

Tags: linux-mint, system-installation, grub, boot-loader, surface

When I try to install [Mint](https://www.reddit.com/r/SurfaceLinux/comments/3w8du2/outofthebox_support_for_linux_mint_173_cinnamon/), I get an error saying:

```
(Some stuff I didn't record, can get if necessary)......Without the GRUB boot loader, the installed system will not boot
```

Things I've tried:

1: Disabling hibernation. Actually, this results in an error "Unable to perform operation", but I've been taking that to mean it's already off, since I can't hibernate anyway

2: Disabling fast startup (In Control Panel Power Options)

3: Sacrificing a goat to the Linux deities

4: Adding 500 MB to the /boot directory when installing. This did nothing, normally I've just been giving 2000 MB swap and 75000 MB root ('/')

5: Disabling Secure Boot (In the UEFI settings)

Any help? My thought at this point is just to install GRUB or another bootloader (suggestions?) separately before Mint, then installing Mint so Mint doesn't have to do it itself, because I'm really not sure why it's not working. At the very least that might give a more detailed error message I'm thinking?

Answer (score 1):

So, after a few more attempts, what finally worked was using [Rufus](https://rufus.akeo.ie/) instead of [PenDriveLinux](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/) to create the bootable USB. I think this is because Mint couldn't find Grub somehow on the first USB drive - it found it fine with Rufus and now works great!